# Python 3.11 poor time.sleep resolution on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sleep, python-3.11

Python 3.11 [introduces a high-resolution timer for time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#time) on Windows. Previously, the best sleep resolution was 1ms (although in practice it was often 16ms unless you engaged in winmm `timeBeginPeriod` trickery).

Upon upgrading to Python 3.11, I expected time.sleep to become vastly more accurate, since the documentation specifies that the new high-resolution timer on Windows "provides resolution of 100 nanoseconds".

However, if I pass a very small value to time.sleep, the best I seem to get is ~0.5 milliseconds. Not bad, but a far cry from "100 nanoseconds".
I am running with Python 3.11.4 on Windows 11 Pro 22H2.

For instance, consider the following snippet:

```
import time
start = time.time_ns()
time.sleep(1e-6)  # sleep for 1 microsecond
end = time.time_ns()
print((end - start) / 1e3)  # prints anywhere between 200-800 microseconds, not ~1 microsecond
```

I can also plot this resolution of 0.5ms across a larger range of inputs:

```
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

expected = []
actual = []
for t in range(1, 10_000, 10):
    start = time.perf_counter_ns()
    time.sleep(t * 1e-6)  # sleep for `t` microseconds
    end = time.perf_counter_ns()
    expected.append(t)
    actual.append((end - start) / 1e3)
plt.plot([1, 10_000], [1, 10_000], label="Expected", c="orange")
plt.scatter(expected, actual, label="Actual")
plt.xlabel("Input to time.sleep (microseconds)")
plt.ylabel("Result (microseconds)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which produces [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA3CN.png). You can see the "steps" every 500 microseconds.

How would I actually get something close to 100ns sleep resolution?

Comment: @KellyBundy Good one, updated the link, script and plot