# Accuracy of time.sleep() module in Python

Tags: python

To check the accuracy of sleep in Python, I used the following two functions to calculate how much data is different in one second
The strange thing is that the output of these two functions was exactly the same, which means that both functions are running at the same speed

Why is that?
My Python version: 3.12

my result:

`loop_1/pps: 64, loop_2/pps: 66`
`loop_1/pps: 65, loop_2/pps: 65`
`loop_1/pps: 64, loop_2/pps: 65`
`loop_1/pps: 64, loop_2/pps: 65`

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

nl_1, nl_2 = 0, 0
last_nl_1, last_nl_2 = 0, 0


def loop_1():
    global nl_1
    while True:
        nl_1 += 1
        sleep(0.01)


def loop_2():
    global nl_2
    while True:
        nl_2 += 1
        sleep(0.0000001)


Thread(target=loop_1).start()
Thread(target=loop_2).start()

while True:
    print(f"loop_1/pps: {nl_1 - last_nl_1}, loop_2/pps: {nl_2 - last_nl_2}")
    last_nl_1, last_nl_2 = nl_1, nl_2
    sleep(1)
```

I tested a few things and found that it is accurate up to one hundredth of a second

**This can solve the problem, but I want an alternative to the python sleep method:**

```py
def loop_2():
    global nl_2
    sleep_time = 0.0001
    max_acc = 0.01
    while True:
        if sleep_time < max_acc:
            for i in range(int(max_acc / sleep_time)):
                nl_2 += 1
            sleep(max_acc)
        else:
            nl_2 += 1
            sleep(sleep_time)
```

Edit: **It seems to work more accurately for some people, probably because of their operating system. Do you have a solution for me?**

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. `loop_1/pps: 100, loop_2/pps: 360072` is just one example of what the above code prints.

Comment: I mean, I can imagine a single CPU system where the output you posted might be possible from the code you posted, but not on modern-day hardware unless you do something special.

Comment: What operating systems are you two using? @khachik

Comment: @khachik

It is strange, it probably gives different answers in different systems

My operating system is Windows

Comment: What's your `sys.getswitchinterval()` and does it help if you make it smaller?

Comment: @KellyBundy
No, it doesn't work, it gives the same answer on two different operating systems with different accuracies

Result for me:  0.005

Comment: Not sure whether the sleep or the threads are the problem. Sleeping apparently got better, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76506785/12671057) which tests and plots sleeping accuracy.

Comment: @KellyBundy

`from time import sleep, time; start = time(); sleep(0.0000001); print(time() - start)`
result: 0.01328277587890625

**It can be said that most of the problems are due to sleep**

Comment: *Do you have a solution for me?* Well, what exactly is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @Homer512
Python sleep method is not accurate for me.
I am looking for a more accurate method.

Comment: Does this happen if you run the two loops sequentially, rather than simultaneously with threads?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm sure. The problem is with the sleep method of Python. I even tested this in a different way with multi-threaded processing

Comment: The OS may have a minimal granularity for sleep.

Comment: @radin The `sleep` method doesn't claim that it can guarantee exactness: *"The suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount, because of the scheduling of other activity in the system."* https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: If you want a "more accurate" `sleep` you may need to do one or more of the following: 1) pin your process to a core; 2) increase the OS priority of the process; 3) ensure your CPU isn't loaded; 4) try a lower level programming language; 5) change operating systems (ideally to RTOS)

Comment: @slothrop Thanks, is there a method to guarantee accuracy?

Comment: Some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657734/sleep-for-exact-time-in-python

Comment: You are dealing with layers of issues here: The OS may delay waking up to conserve energy. CPython is inherently single-threaded with a global interpreter lock (GIL), so another thread may delay your timing thread from running. The system may be busy and not schedule your thread. The sleep system call itself may have low granularity. Which of these issues are you aware of, willing to accept, or trying to work around? Also at what cost, e.g. CPU time? What delays are you looking for and what jitter can you accept?